# Get a list of supported GPU engine types

Tags: powershell, gpu, c#, wmi

I am trying to pull GPU metrics off WMI/ Powershell

From my research I gathered that the GPU usage is segregated into different "Engine Types" (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/gpus-in-the-task-manager/)

This is also observable in WMI explorer as instances of the `Win32_PerfFormattedData_GPUPerformanceCounters_GPUEngine` class

[image: This is also observable in WMI explorer]

My question is, **is there any list of enums or mappings available which exposes this data?**

Comment: Does [DXGK_ENGINE_TYPE (d3dkmdt.h) - Windows drivers | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/d3dkmdt/ne-d3dkmdt-dxgk_engine_type) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DXGI API to get the LUID and associate it with the graphics card.

Like this:

```
  ComPtr<IDXGIFactory> dxgiFactory;
  if (FAILED(CreateDXGIFactory(IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxgiFactory)))) {
    std::wcerr << "Cannot create DXGI factory, exiting" << std::endl;
  }

  UINT i = 0;
  IDXGIAdapter* adapter = nullptr;
  while (dxgiFactory->EnumAdapters(i, &adapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND) {
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC desc;
    adapter->GetDesc(&desc);
    std::wcout << "DXGI Adapter:  " << desc.Description
               << " - LUID: " << desc.AdapterLuid << std::endl;
    adapter->Release();
    ++i;
  }
```